# how do i load image from resource inside TembeddedWB

Tags: html, delphi, delphi-xe7, twebbrowser

iam trying to load image from resource inside image htmlTag as example

```
<img src="'+ Resourceimage +'">
```

i tried to do something like this

```
function getFullHTML(res:string):string;
var
  sURL : string;
  resorceimg : TResourceStream;
  begin
  resorceimg := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, res, RT_RCDATA);
    sURL  := 'res://'+ resorceimg +'';
  end;
```

then i call the function like this

```
<img src="'+ getFullHTML('imagename') +'">
```

but i cannot use a `TResourceStream` into string i think iam doing it in horrible way how exactly i can load image from resource into html image ?

Comment: [How to create and use HTML resource files](http://delphidabbler.com/articles?article=10)

Comment: kobik this should be an answer , thank you very much its solved my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Data URIs with Base64 encoded images:

[Embedding Base64 Images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1207190/embedding-base64-images)

The image is then embedded like

```
<img alt="Embedded Image" src="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAADIA..." />
```

The anwers to the linked question list supported browsers.

Comment: Thank you mjn its useful data